# How do I write this SQL Query to join these three tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables that I need to query in order to get my results.

```
Table 1 has an AppId and a ProjectID
Table2 has an AppID and an AppName.  
Table 3 has a ProjectID and a ProjectName
```

I want to get out of this a list, By AppName, the ProjectNames they are tied to.

So far, a basic query to get what I want works, but I only get the ID's.  I need to somehow join these to get the names associated.  I need to somehow join this to table2 with the project name information, and table 2 with the appname information.

Select * from Table1 ( this table has only ID's, not names)
   Order by AppId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables like this:

```
Select t2.AppName, t3.ProjectName
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.AppID = t1.AppID
inner join table3 t3 on t3.ProjectID = t1.ProjectID
```

Comment: Great help!  I got that to work.  My boss now has asked that I add a 4th requirement.  I'll end up posting that as a second question! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I'll keep an eye out for your next question too